# É possível referenciar um alias em MySQL e usar seu valor de campo?

Tags: mysql, data, alias

Estou com a seguinte situação:
Um ponto eletrônico em mySQL e trabalhando numa consulta que faz diversos cálculos com datas e horários.

```
select
nome_colaborador,
date_format(data_registro, "%d %M %Y") as Dia, 
time_format(hora_entrada, "%Hh %i")  as Entrada, 
time_format(hora_saida, "%Hh %i")  as Saída,
time_format(timediff(hora_saida, hora_entrada), "%Hh %i") as 'Tempo de Presença'
from ponto_eletronico
join colaborador on colaborador_matricula_colaborador = matricula_colaborador;
;
```

A dúvida é: vou adicionar um novo campo que é "Saldo de horas", nada mais é do que subtrair o total de horas que a pessoa tem a cumprir nesse dia, com o quanto ela cumpriu nesse dia (as 'tempo Presença') então, quero saber se tem um jeito de fazer uma referência pra esse alias ao invés de ter que incluir o cálculo todo novamente.

Comment: *"se tem um jeito de fazer uma referência pra esse alias ao invés de ter que incluir o cálculo todo novamente"* eu li não não ficou claro, pode colocar como ficaria a query para ilustrar melhor?

Comment: Queria que o próximo campo fosse calculadoassim: timediff('Tempo de Presença','<Jornada>')

Jornada é um valor que vai variar dependendo do usuário e não importa pra dúvida, mas sim a parte de tentar pegar o alias 'Tempo de presença' pra por no cálculo

Comment: e "Jornada" é o alias certo? se for isso não da pra usar na mesma query :(

Comment: Colega, como expliquei, jornada não importa pra dúvida, ele vai ser um campo registrado na tabela.

Comment: O que eu quero saber é se a parte do  'Tempo de presença', alias de um campo gerado a partir de cálculos feitos com os dados de hora_entrada e hora_saida, possa ser usado para calcular outro campo